# How to create json data same structure in excel sheet?

Tags: node.js, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I have a doubt how to JSON structure maintain in excel sheet. I tried to JSON data convert to excel sheet using an online tool. I got the excel sheet. but JSON object structure not in the excel sheet. can give some suggestion node js code used to convert json data to excel data.

**JSON DATA**

```
{
product_name:bourbon,
product_image:
{
image1:image 
image2:image
}
}
```

**I tried to convert JSON to Excel using an online tool**
There are two columns product_name showing bourbon but product_image showing the only value key is not showing how to fix it.
product_name ------  product_image
bourbon                image
                       image

Comment: I have another doubt this excel sheet I will use to convert JSON format. that JSON format same as my input JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

If you want output like this

```
product_name    product_image__image1   product_image__image2
bourbon .       image                   image
```

Then you can use [this](https://json-csv.com/).

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** – Login to the [GST Portal](https://www.gst.gov.in/)

**Step 2** – Go to ‘Services’ > ‘Returns’ > ‘Returns Dashboard’

[image: 2]]

**Step 3** – Select the ‘Financial Year’ and ‘Return Filing Period’ from the drop-down

[image: 3]]

**Step 4** – Click on ‘DOWNLOAD’ button under GSTR 2A.

[image: 4]]

**Step 5** – Click on ‘GENERATE FILE’ and download the JSON file.

[image: 5]]

**Step 6** – Upload the JSON file and convert it to Excel format using a JSON to Excel converter available online.